# React app deploying on heroku, not loading DB from mlab

Tags: reactjs

When I run heroku local, app working as expecting. 
On production, it's not loading anything from Mlab (remote mongoDb)

Here is it 
https://react-bulletin.herokuapp.com/

Just showing static react file.

here is my server file

```
require('dotenv').config();

// Express Stuff
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')
// Mongo Wrapper
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// Supporting Libraries
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Globals
const dbUrl = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const port = process.env.PORT

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false
});

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', require('./Routes'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Serve any static files
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
```

I have no idea why is that. 
Please any help.

PS 
MONGODB_URI is added to heroku varibles.

Comment: `mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false }).catch(error => console.log(error));` - try to catch the error while connecting to the db, you may get some usefull information

Comment: it's no error. Build succeeded. No issue.

Comment: Can you show your axios call? I think its because you are fetching the wrong url

Comment: You right! I'm calling a localhost )